# Is there way to spyOnProperty window.location.search using jasmine unit testing? because search is not configurable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Its throwing error: search is not configurable

```
it('should have search keyword', function () {
  spyOnProperty(window.location, 'search').and.returnValue("?q=jag");
  expect(window.location.search).toBe("?q=jag");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
beforeEach(function () {
  window.history.pushState({}, '', "?q=jag");
})
it('should have search keyword', function () {
  expect(window.location.search).toBe("?q=jag");
  expect($('#decoder-search-bar-input').val()).toEqual('jag');
});
```